# need help to update the values in an object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I’m struggling to code for this task.
This is the code I have done it returns an object but I don't know how to update the objects as required.

```
function updateObj(obj,keyName,val) {
    obj = {};  
    keyName = this.keyName;
    val = this.val;
   
    if (val === obj.val) {
        val;
    } else {
        obj.val;
    }
   obj = {
       keyName: keyName,
       val
   };
   return obj;
}
```

below is what the outcome should be.

```
const bag = {
    color: 'yellow',
    hasMoney: false
}
updateObj(wallet, 'color', 'Blue'); => { color: 'Blue', hasMoney: false }

const house = {
    sqFt: 1500,
    isOccupied: true
}
updateObj(house, 'sqFt', 2000); // => { sqFt: 2000, isOccupied: true }

const cat = { isFurry: false };
const propName = 'isFurry';

cat['propName'] = true;
console.log(cat); // => { isFurry: false, propName: true }
```

Comment: Your function makes not a lot of sense to me. Can you explain why you don't use it as in your last example. Why do you have a `if else` if it doesn't do anything?

Comment: Also why do you overwrite the paramters passed into the function with `this.[...]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've overcomplicated the problem. It can be as simple as

```js
function updateObj(obj,keyName,val) {
   obj[keyName] = val;
   return obj;
}

const bag = {
    color: 'yellow',
    hasMoney: false
}
console.log(updateObj(bag, 'color', 'Blue')); // => { color: 'Blue', hasMoney: false }

const house = {
    sqFt: 1500,
    isOccupied: true
}
console.log(updateObj(house, 'sqFt', 2000)); // => { sqFt: 2000, isOccupied: true }

const cat = { isFurry: false };
const propName = 'isFurry';

cat['propName'] = true;
console.log(cat); // => { isFurry: false, propName: true }
```

`updateObj` modifies the input object and sets a property. At the end it returns the reference to the input object. You can discard the return statement if you don't need it

```js
function updateObj(obj,keyName,val) {
   obj[keyName] = val;
}

const bag = {
    color: 'yellow',
    hasMoney: false
}
updateObj(bag, 'color', 'Blue');
console.log(bag); // => { color: 'Blue', hasMoney: false }

const house = {
    sqFt: 1500,
    isOccupied: true
}
updateObj(house, 'sqFt', 2000);
console.log(house); // => { sqFt: 2000, isOccupied: true }

const cat = { isFurry: false };
const propName = 'isFurry';

cat['propName'] = true;
console.log(cat); // => { isFurry: false, propName: true }
```

Creating a shallow copy using the spread operator is even simpler

```js
function updateObj(obj,keyName,val) {
   return { ...obj, [keyName]: val };
}

const bag = {
    color: 'yellow',
    hasMoney: false
}
console.log(updateObj(bag, 'color', 'Blue')); // => { color: 'Blue', hasMoney: false }

const house = {
    sqFt: 1500,
    isOccupied: true
}
console.log(updateObj(house, 'sqFt', 2000)); // => { sqFt: 2000, isOccupied: true }

const cat = { isFurry: false };
const propName = 'isFurry';

cat['propName'] = true;
console.log(cat); // => { isFurry: false, propName: true }
```

but in that case the function name could be confusing, because the input object isn't updated.

Comment: Thank you this code works.  I did do one similar to this, could you please explain why mine did not work but yours did.                                                                
   function updateObj(obj,keyName,val) {
   obj.Keyname  = val;
   return obj;
}

Comment: @Codinglyn Your code also updates the object, but it doesn't return anything explicitly and it sets the wrong key. `obj.Keyname` is equivalent to `obj['Keyname']`. You need the bracket operator, because you want `obj[Keyname]` and that's not possible with the dot operator.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function updateObj(obj, keyName, val) {
  if (obj) {
      if (obj[keyName] != undefined){
        obj[keyName] = val;
      }
      return obj;
  }
}

const bag = {
    color: 'yellow',
    hasMoney: false
}
console.log(updateObj(bag, 'color', 'Blue'));
//console.log(updateObj(null, 'color', 'Blue'));
//console.log(updateObj(bag, 'food', 'Blue'));
const house = {
    sqFt: 1500,
    isOccupied: true
}
console.log(updateObj(house, 'sqFt', 2000));
```

You should check the object is not null and the object has that key, otherwise it may return unexpected result.